# Word2vec: distangling semantic from syntactic

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I want to use pre-train word vectors (e.g., fasttest on Wikipedia) to find clusters of a set of words. However, in the list of words I have words like 'kindness', 'kind', 'kindly' and they fall in different clusters. That is sometimes words with similar part of speech are clusters together. I want to know how can I have word vectors that only captures meaning?

Comment: Please provide some good example of what you want to do

Comment: I have a list of words (e.g., 'kind','kindness', 'honest','honesty', 'kindly') i find the vectors for each word from fasttext, reduce the dimension of the vector space and do a kmeans clustering on the top of that. I'm expecting words like kind, kindness and kindly be in the same cluster. However, words with similar part of speech go to the same cluster instead.

Comment: Have you tried clustering without dimensionality reduction. Have you checked plain Euclidean distance with pairs of words you're interested in

Comment: I tried the without dimensionality reduction but the result is not convincing. What do you mean by Euclidean distance?

Comment: that's plain distance between the vectors

Comment: that is how the current kmeans work without dimensionality reduction. I'm interested in their cluster as opposed to pairwise comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lemmatize or stem the words before using word2vec.

[stemming](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stemming/1.0) library has several such algorithm implemented.

Comment: The problem with stemming is that it transforms words to the root of the word, e.g., "house" and "housing" -> "hous" which do not exist in pre-train word2vec model.

Comment: Then use a lemmatizer